# unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python

```
while True:
    no=input()
    if no=='':
        break
    else:
        split_change(no)
```

This gives EOF error, how to check for EOF while getting input from std input ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
  while True:
    try:
      no=raw_input()
      if no=='':
        break
      else:
        split_change(no)
    except EOFError:
      break
```

EDIT: changed input() to raw_input(), and realized that you have to use try/except otherwise you still get the error.

EDIT2: Changed 1 to True

Comment: @jchl: +1. Yes. That would be better. I edited the answer. Thanks.