# User Input for Python in TextMate

Tags: python, textmate

I am using python in TextMate and I want to get user input, the code is:

```
f = raw_input("Please enter your search term? ")
```

However when I run it in TextMate the following error appear

> EOF when reading a line

but no problem when I run it in console, any one has any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [raw_input causing EOFError after creating exe with py2exe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280889/raw-input-causing-eoferror-after-creating-exe-with-py2exe)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217258/unexpected-eof-while-parsing

Answer (score 3):

The only solution initially in my experience was to run the script from the command line i.e. outside of Textmate. However, further research shown that if one installed the file tm_interactive_input.dylib from https://github.com/alkemist/interactive-input/downloads
in the location specified on the Macromates blog ( http://blog.macromates.com/2009/interactive-input/ ) this worked.

Comment: Works great with Snow Leopard. Will the next Textmate version include this by default again?

Answer (score 1):

Try command key + shift + R to run it in terminal instead.